# Webbrowser1 keeps opening pdf in new window

Tags: vb.net, pdf, browser

I am using the following code to open up a pdf

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("file://C:\test.pdf")
```

However instead of opening up in the browser it just keeps on launching adobe acrobat reader and opening the PDF in that, leaving the webbrowser1 untouched.

This is not what I want; I want my PDF to open up in my web browser

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Is your PDF actually within your solution?

Comment: you mean is my PDF realy found at C:\MYPDF.pdf then the answer is yes. I did however install explorer 8 the other day and if I Type file://C:\MYPDF.pdf in the adress bar it also fails to show the PDF in the browser which it never use to? is there a setting in explorer i need to enable first?

Comment: If my answer doesn't work then post more code please, as mine is functioning fine.

Comment: it has somthing todo with IE8 more people are complaining about it and i checked the other pcs with older versions of IE works like a charm on them..

Comment: Yeah, try using chrome, that's what I work on and I've never had any problems!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this. What you need to do is drag your pdf document to your solution explorer and then open it from there.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("c:\users\Fake.Name\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SO\SO\test.pdf")
End Sub
```

I am working on solution 'SO', so I put the pdf into the solution and dragged the pdf to my code where it generated its location.

Also, take a look at [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6814313_enable-pdf-browser.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer makes absolutely no sense.  Most deployed, built, programs dynamically load documents at run time based on user selection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the "file" statment.

Try this

WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\test.pdf")

And you'll see the file opened into your webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties check "Prefer 32-bit". Of course, that might bring on other problems (as in my case), so it's not a perfect solution.